# How to copy and paste a small matrix into a bigger matrix without for-loop

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, copy, paste

For example, we have a small matrix

```
B = [5 2, 
     3 4]
```

and the bigger one

```
A = [1 0 0 0 0
     0 1 0 0 0
     0 0 1 0 0
     0 0 0 1 0
     0 0 0 0 1]
```

Now I want paste B into A so that A looks like

```
A = [1 0 0 0 0
     0 1 0 0 0
     0 0 1 0 0
     0 0 0 5 2
     0 0 0 3 4]
```

That means the values of A of the bottom right has been replaced. I would like to do this without using a for-loop. How is that possible?

PS:

1. A is always an eye(n) matrix (n is a constant).
2. B  is a square matrix and has a variable size but is always less or equal to A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the relevant row and column subscripts of `A` and put `B` there.

```
A(end-size(B,1)+1:end, end-size(B,2)+1:end)=B
```

It works even if `B` is not a square matrix.